# Longtable, ltablex and ThreePartTable - rows misaligned

Tags: longtable, ltablex, threeparttablex

I collected fragments of several answers to arrive here, but still there is some problem in my code that I can't find. I'm trying to make a long table (2-3 pages) with text width using the `ltablex` package in a *ThreePartTable* environment.

I have two problems:

1. my tablenotes: the footnote of the table - they are wrapped to another page, disconnected from the last lines of the table.
2. last row before break have second line in next page

Minimal working example below:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    %Set Margin
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb, mathtools}

    %Spacing
    \usepackage{setspace}

    %Tables
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{here}
    \usepackage{ltablex,array}
    \usepackage{threeparttablex}

    \begin{document}

    \onehalfspacing
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C*{9}{c}}   
    \caption{Basic Statistics}\label{tab:1}\\

    \hline
    BBB  & $\#$ BBBBB & $\#$ BBBB & $\#$ BBB & BBBB  & BBB. BBB. & BB    & $\Delta \%$ BBBB & $\Delta \%$ BBB. BBB. \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\
    \hline
    BBB  & $\#$ BBBBB & $\#$ BBBB & $\#$ BBB & BBBB  & BBB. BBB. & BB    & $\Delta \%$ BBBB & $\Delta \%$ BBB. BBB. \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
    \endfoot

    \hline
    \endlastfoot        

\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
\multirow{2}[1]{*}{0} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{000} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{00} & 000   & 000   & 00,000 & 00,000 & 0    & 0 \\
&&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00) \\
    \end{tabularx}   
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
          \item Source: Our elaboration. Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.Our elaboration.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{center}  
    \end{ThreePartTable}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your use of `multirow` is unusual, What it their purpose? Also number of defined columns (10) and used (9) not agree. You have more off-topic problems in table, however, lenght of your table doesn't allow that table notes be fir completely on one page (below of table)

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks! The first column will have an id, and the last 6 columns will have double lines (like mean and sd). Where exactly the columns dont agree? See that there is a special definition of column there, so Im aiming to 9 columns.  Regarding the table notes, I would like that the break contemplate the cut where the notes would be complete, the same way that would happen to a figure. Thanks!

Comment: What you claim, is not done i table.  See my answer below. for this you need reorganize your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

In the first reading of your MWE I overlooked purpose of used `multirows`. Now I return them into MWE with more simple (and correct) syntax. This happen since usually for this is not used `\multirow`, but  standard cells aligned with top of row pairs. This gives better readability of table contents.

With your table you are "lucky" that it size doesn't enable to keep table notes in one page. A simple solution is change table size so, that fr example last row pairs and table notes are on the same page. this can be achieved also with move table start lower on the page.

Your table has many off-topic :

- Number of declared columns (10) disagree with used  (9), so in my test I add empty column on right side of table (or you can reduce number of used, it is not clear which action givers desired table design)
- To preserve functionality of `X` column type it is necessary to add `\keepXColumns` in preamble or before table
- Use rules from `booktabs` package fives more professional looks to table. Also adding for example each fifth row `\addlinespece` makes table more easy to red
- You can use `\caption{...}` also for captions on the next pages
- It is not clear, if you like to have `\onehalfspacing` in table. To my opinion is better not and spaces between rows determine with `\arraystreatch˙.

  In MWE below I use between row pairs `\addlinespace`, vertical space between rows in pairs hasn't additional vertical space
- For decimal numbers would be fine to consider use of `S` column type from package `siunitx` (I didn't make this change in MWE below)

After this changes and increasing font size to `\small`
the table span three pages and your problem with `tablenotes` disappear.

Begin of table:

[image]

End of table:

[image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Set Margin
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
%Math
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}
%Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
%Tables
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,
            multirow, ltablex, threeparttablex}
\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
%\onehalfspacing


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \small
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{C*{9}{c}}
\caption{Basic Statistics}\label{tab:1}\\
    \toprule
BBB & $\#$ BBBBB    & $\#$ BBBB             & $\#$ BBB
    & BBBB          & \makecell{BBB.\\ BBB.}& BB
    & \makecell{$\Delta\%$\\ BBBB}          & \makecell{$\Delta \%$\\ BBB.}
    & BBB.\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{ \textit{Continued from previous}}\\
    \toprule
BBB & $\#$ BBBBB    & $\#$ BBBB             & $\#$ BBB
    & BBBB          & \makecell{BBB.\\ BBB.}& BB
    & \makecell{$\Delta\%$\\ BBBB}          & \makecell{$\Delta \%$\\ BBB.}
    & BBB.\\
    \midrule
\endhead
%
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    \addlinespace
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{=}{0}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{000}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{00}
            &   000
                &   000
                    &   00,000
                        &   00,000  &   0   &   0           \\
    &&& (000) & (000) & (00,000) & (00,000) & (00)  & (00)  \\
    \end{tabularx}\footnotesize\raggedright%\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
      \item Source:    Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration. Our elaboration.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I needed but close enough that I could adapt it. Im new to using tabularx and thought that the second {c} meaned the alignment of the previous C column, not a new one. A last question: I tried to implement the siunitx package, but it trows an error - "siunitx error: "invalid-number" - does it ring a bell of what could be causing it?

Comment: On my PC provided MWE works without any error or warnings (tested). Do you change something in it? Do you have all text in `S` columns inside curly braces?

Comment: I'm curious, what exactly you need? I saw some discrepancy in table design and I try to fix them as far as I can guess, what you like to obtain and how I would design similar table. I'm glad that you will able to adapt it to your needs.